# Graph API get country ONLY

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am using the Graph API. When requestion the user's location, it returns a random id and their location, which is in the format of City, Province.

For examaple, for me, it returns: Toronto, Ontario.

Is it possible to request the country only? I know that I can use some geocoding APIs from google to decode it and find out the country, but is it possible to get it directly from fb

Here's my request path:
 `NSString *requestPath = @"me/ fields=first_name,last_name,location,gender,birthday,relationship_status,email";`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The country as a value by itself is only ever passed to Page Tabs & Canvas Apps through a `signed_request`. All other methods pass a location as defined by the user, which is to say, there's no guarantee it reflects their **actual** location. Just something to consider, depending on how you plan to use that info.